# Flash/iPhone game development framework

Tags: mobile, frameworks, cross-platform, sparrow-framework

I've been a php/ruby/flash/android/iphone developer for quite some time. I'm starting my mobile/browser game development career. I've been searching for a cross-platform framework that would be the best choice for me as a beginner. I fond the Sparrow framework (iPhone) but I'm not sure about it.

Btw... I'll start with simple games (racing or super mario-style).

My questions:
- Which framework should I use?
- Is it possible to create a game in flash and then export it to native OS (iPhone,Android,Symbian).
- I like screen casts (video tutorials), where can I found them?
- Other tips?

Thx 10x!

Answer (score 1):

Using flash is very different than any other framework ive used. Flash takes care of almost everything for you (ie. Loading images, sprites, animations, etc.) while other languages/frameworks require this to be done manually unless you use a game engine. If you are looking to develop on the iphone cocos2d is a good framework to use. Starting from flash and moving to a different framework would be harder than starting with a different framework and moving to flash.

Comment: I don't know of any cross-platform frameworks that can be used acros computers and mobile environments except for jMonkeyEngine which has some Android support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flash, but unless your game is turn based I wouldn't recommend it.  The Adobe packager is still dirt slow.

If you want something that is cross platform and pretty easy to get into you should check out Unity3D.  It's mostly 3D specific, but has some user created 2D addons.  You can use ECMA style syntax as well so it wouldn't be a huge leap away from flash.